# How to set the x axis while plotting from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

My data is saved as columns in a dataframe. I want to be able to apply functions to each column and plot all the columns together as they are one set. I can use df.plot() to plot them togther but I would like to set the x-axis separately. It is not included in the dataframe. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the quickest would be to set your x-values as the rows index of your dataframe. You can do this either before or after you have made your modifications to the dataframe column values. The [`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method will automatically use the rows index values for the x-axis. As a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example dataframe
y1 = np.sin(np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1))
y2 = np.cos(np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1))
y3 = np.cos(2 * np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1))
df = pd.DataFrame({"y1": y1, "y2": y2, "y3": y3})

# Initialize example x-values 1D array
x = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)

# Set `x` array as rows index of the dataframe
df.index = x

# Generate a plot with three curves (one for each dataframe column)
df.plot()
```

[image: dataframe plot]

Answer (score -1):

this is to be the value of x may have to be in the what ever they want to be in the plot. likewise it is given below.

```
import matplotlib.py plot as plt

import numpy as np

x=[3,6,9,12,15,18]

y=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xticks(range(20))

plt.show()
```

here x ticks is used for change the x axis points

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: x ticks is used to name the graph that is in the x plot axis here we have to x ticks(value)